# FoxPro and old softwares

Tags: software-design, visual-foxpro, windows-xp-sp3

I have an old software running on XP. When I run it on another pc the following error arises

> odbc driver manager, data source name not found and no default driver specified.

How do I get around this problem?

Note: on the old system I checked in administrative tools in data source is has foxpro drivers.

Comment: This is a question about how to install your software.

Answer (score 1):

Technically that message looks like a failed attempt to create an ODBC connection via DSN ("Data Source Name") which does not exist. VFP Command Window example:

```
? SQLCONNECT("DsnDoesNotExist")
AERROR(laErrors)
DISPLAY MEMORY LIKE laErrors
```

If the original maintainer of your software did not provide any "setup" documentation, you can find the Name of the required Data Source in the source code, either as code line(s) using Vfp's `SqlConnect()`function, or as a "Connection" object stored in a Vfp myDatabase.DBC

If you have not got the source code, you can try to find the related "User DSN" or "System DSN" in the Windows "ODBC Data Source Administrator" of the old PC.
That DSN would contain the required connection string including driver info, e.g. "PostgreSQL" or "MS SQL Native Client", etc.
If the new system is a 64bit version, you'd need to use the 32bit version of the administration tool (usually C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\odbcad32.exe) in order to recreate the DSN there.

FWIW, Vfp itself does not necessarily need a "DSN" for ODBC connections - if you've got the source code, see the `SqlStringConnect()` function in the VFP documentation or try a web search